# How to run a custom script on npm build/run events in a package

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, code-generation, sourcegenerators

I am trying to build a source code generator that reads from a file and generates code in the project.

I want this script to run on build/run events. What is the correct way to do so? I would also prefer to be able to use typescript for this and for it to work as an NPM package